# SQLite3 Update statement not updating Database

Tags: python, sqlite

Mac OS latest update
Python 3 latest update
standard SQLite3 library

GUI development library PySimpleGUI

My problem is that my UPDATE Statement does not update the database and as a consequence my PySimpleGUI table element does not update in my GUI window.

I have around 2 months experience in coding using PySimpleGUI and have learned the value of research (as my code will suggest... I hope).

I have read the docs for (and extensively searched) both my GUI Library Docs and the SQLite Docs.

I am aware that this CRUD isn't fully ready (DELETE not working will fix once I understand what I am doing wrong with UPDATE)
I really need to understand why this is not working so I can wrap my head around Query syntax so I can write my delete statement and write some custom queries across multiple tables.(This knowledge will come in time.)

Sorry for the volumous code here, best you see the whole CRUD Form.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import sqlite3
from sqlite3 import Error

sg.Theme=('Purple')

def Customer_CRUD():
    
    def retrieve_customer():

        cust_details=[]
        conn=sqlite3.connect('Accounts.db')
        cursor=conn.execute('SELECT ID,Name,Bill,Site,Phone,Email FROM Customers')
        for row in cursor:
            cust_details.append(list(row))
        return cust_details

    table_data=retrieve_customer()

    headings=['ID','Name','Bill Address','Site Address','Phone','Email']

    cust_window_layout=[
        [sg.T('Customer CRUD For',font=('ariel',16))],
        [sg.T('Customer ID:',font=('ariel',14)),sg.InputText(font=('ariel',14),key='-ID-',disabled_readonly_background_color='Grey',disabled=True)],
        [sg.T('Customer Name:',font=('ariel',14)),sg.InputText(font=('ariel',14),size=(50,1),key='-Name-')],
        [sg.T('Billing Address:',font=('ariel',14)),sg.InputText(font=('ariel',14),size=(50,1),key='-Bill-')],
        [sg.T('Site Address:',font=('ariel',14)),sg.InputText(font=('ariel',14),size=(50,1),key='-Site-')],
        [sg.T('Phone:',font=('ariel',14)),sg.InputText(font=('ariel',14),size=(10,1),key='-Phone-'),sg.T('Email:',font=('ariel',14)),sg.InputText(font=('ariel',14),size=(25,1),key='-Email-')],
        [sg.Button('Submit',font=('ariel',16)),sg.Button('Update',font=('ariel',16)),sg.Button('Delete',font=('ariel',16))],
        [sg.Table(values=table_data,headings=headings,
                  font=('ariel',14),
                  max_col_width=50,
                  display_row_numbers=False,
                  justification='center',
                  vertical_scroll_only=False,
                  select_mode=sg.TABLE_SELECT_MODE_BROWSE,
                  num_rows=10,
                  enable_events=True,
                  key='-Table-')],
        [sg.Button('Main',font=('ariel',16)),sg.Button('Back',font=('riel',16))],
         ]
                  
    cust_window=sg.Window('Pool Resurfacing NQ Accounts',cust_window_layout)

    #define all sub processes here

    def clear_input():
        for key in values:
            cust_window[key]('')
            return None
        
    def add_customer(Name,Bill,Site,Phone,Email):

        conn=sqlite3.connect('Accounts.db')
        cursor=conn.execute('INSERT INTO Customers(Name,Bill,Site,Phone,Email) \
            VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)', (Name,Bill,Site,Phone,Email))
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()

        sg.Popup('Values successfully added',font=('ariel',16))

        cust_window['-Table-'].update(table_data)
        cust_window.refresh()

    def update_customer(Name,Bill,Site,Phone,Email,ID):

            conn=sqlite3.connect('Accounts.db')
            cursor=conn.execute('UPDATE Customers SET Name=?,Bill=?,Site=?,Phone=?,Email=? WHERE ID=?', (str(Name),str(Bill),str(Site),str(Phone),str(Email),str(ID)))
            conn.commit()
            conn.close()

            sg.Popup('Values successfully updated',font=('ariel',16))

            retrieve_customer()
            cust_window['-Table-'].update(table_data)
            cust_window.refresh()
            
    def delete_customer():

        conn=sqlite3.connect('Accounts.db')
        cursor=conn.execute('Delete FROM Customers \
            WHERE ID=cust_window["-ID-"]')
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()
        sg.Popup('Values successfully deleted',font=('ariel',16))
        cust_window['-Table-'].update(table_data)
        cust_window.refresh()

    while True:

        event,values=cust_window.read()

        if event==sg.WIN_CLOSED:
            break

        if event=='Submit':

            name=values['-Name-']
            if name=='':
                sg.popup('Missing Information:','Customer Name')

            bill=values['-Bill-']
            if bill=='':
                sg.popup('Missing Information:','Billing Address')

            site=values['-Site-']
            if site=='':
                sg.popup('Missing Information:','Site Address')

            phone=values['-Phone-']
            if phone=='':
                sg.popup('Missing Information:','Phone Number')

            email=values['-Email-']
            if email=='':
                sg.popup('Missing Information:','Email Address')

            else:
                add_customer(values['-Name-'],values['-Bill-'],values['-Site-'],values['-Phone-'],values['-Email-'])
                sg.popup('Your record has been saved successfully',font=('ariel',16))
                clear_input()

        if event=='-Table-':

            try:
                row=values['-Table-'][0]
                table_value=table_data[row]

                for i in table_value:
                    cust_window['-ID-'].update(table_value[0])
                    cust_window['-Name-'].update(table_value[1])
                    cust_window['-Bill-'].update(table_value[2])
                    cust_window['-Site-'].update(table_value[3])
                    cust_window['-Phone-'].update(table_value[4])
                    cust_window['-Email-'].update(table_value[5])
            except IndexError:
                continue

        if event=='Update':

            NAME=cust_window['-Name-']
            BILL=cust_window['-Bill-']
            SITE=cust_window['-Site-']
            PHONE=cust_window['-Phone-']
            EMAIL=cust_window['-Email-']
            IDENT=cust_window['-ID-']
            
            update_customer(NAME,BILL,SITE,PHONE,EMAIL,IDENT)

        if event=='Delete':
            delete_customer()


        if event=='Main':
            None#main_menu()

        if event=='Back':
            None#income()

    cust_window.close()
            
Customer_CRUD()
```

Thank you all in advance for your assistance!

Answer (score 1):

If nothing wrong, IMO, your database updated, but not correctly update the Table element.

- `retrieve_customer()` return `cust_details` from your database, but the result not kept
- `cust_window['-Table-'].update(table_data)` update the Table element with old `table_data` which not updated.

Maybe it should be like this

```py
    def update_customer(Name,Bill,Site,Phone,Email,ID):

            conn=sqlite3.connect('Accounts.db')
            cursor=conn.execute('UPDATE Customers SET Name=?,Bill=?,Site=?,Phone=?,Email=? WHERE ID=?', (str(Name),str(Bill),str(Site),str(Phone),str(Email),str(ID)))
            conn.commit()
            conn.close()

            sg.Popup('Values successfully updated',font=('ariel',16))

            table_data = retrieve_customer()    # Keep the returned list `cust_details`
            cust_window['-Table-'].update(table_data)
            cust_window.refresh()
```

Here, with a simple code to demo

```py
import sqlite3
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def retrieve_customer():
    cust_details=[]
    cursor=conn.execute('SELECT ID,Name,Bill,Site,Phone,Email FROM Customers')
    for row in cursor:
        cust_details.append(list(row))
    return cust_details

def add_customer(data):
        cursor=conn.execute('INSERT INTO Customers (ID,Name,Bill,Site,Phone,Email) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)', data)
        conn.commit()

conn = sqlite3.connect('Accounts.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Customers (ID TEXT,Name TEXT, Bill TEXT,Site TEXT,Phone TEXT,Email TEXT)''')
conn.commit()

font1, font2 = ('Arial', 14), ('Arial', 16)
sg.theme('Purple')
sg.set_options(font=font1)

headings = ['ID','Name','Bill Address','Site Address','Phone','Email']
fields = {
    '-ID-'      : 'Customer ID:',
    '-Name-'    : 'Customer Name:',
    '-Bill-'    : 'Billing Address:',
    '-Site-'    : 'Site Address:',
    '-Phone-'   : 'Phone:',
    '-Email-'   : 'Email:'}

table_data = retrieve_customer()

layout = [
    [sg.Push(), sg.Text('Customer CRUD'), sg.Push()]] + [
    [sg.Text(text), sg.Push(), sg.Input(key=key)] for key, text in fields.items()] + [
    [sg.Push()] +
    [sg.Button(button) for button in ('Add', 'Delete')] +
    [sg.Push()],
    [sg.Table(values=table_data, headings=headings, max_col_width=50, num_rows=10,
          display_row_numbers=False, justification='center', enable_events=True,
          vertical_scroll_only=False, select_mode=sg.TABLE_SELECT_MODE_BROWSE,
          expand_x=True, key='-Table-')],
    [sg.Button('Main'), sg.Push(), sg.Button('Back')],
]

window = sg.Window('Pool Resurfacing NQ Accounts', layout)
sg.theme('DarkBlue4')

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == 'Add':
        data = tuple(map(lambda key:values[key], fields.keys()))
        if '' in data:
            index = data.index('')
            sg.popup('Missing Information:', list(fields.values())[index][:-1])
        else:
            add_customer(data)
            table_data = retrieve_customer()
            window['-Table-'].update(table_data)

conn.close()
window.close()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @Jason Yang, that line of code exists after the def of Update Customer, would it be better if I do an edit with the full code so far for my CRUD Form?

Comment: Maybe your can check the value return from `retrieve_customer()` to confirm if database updated or not. It will be better if you post an executable script with new dbase before GUI start, then everybody can check what happened.

Comment: I will try that by adding a print statement. that will work wont it?

Comment: I checked the table_data list/array by using it as value in popup after event=='Update', DB didn't update or I didn't call an update to the table_data lis/array properly, I will check my list/array first and go from there.

Comment: I have some homework to get this step right... I just applied clear() method to table_data , and assigned a new list  (cust_deets= retrieve_customer()) and I need to get the right output in the table before I pursue this any further. Thank you for your help so far...

Comment: Homework complete.

Comment: It is definately the SQL Statement not updating the database... which I dont understand as I thought syntax was right (not right obviously). I tested this inside the function Update_cust() by adding a new list cust_deets=retrieve_customer() then calling the retrieve_customer() function , then assigning it to a popup (checking contents of cust_deets) then calling cust_window['-Table-'].update(cust_deets), then cust_window.refresh()

Comment: wow @Jason, just disecting your code you gave in your answer as I was a bit sleepy last night... wow... you tidied up so much of my window with a few lines of code... thank you very much..

Comment: @ Jason, I did a lot of reading and playing with the codes you supplied and enjoyed coming to an understanding of what you did with it.... (I started new un-related codes to experiment and read the docs again focusing on the methods you used and liked the key dictionary) ... this became so simple so thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I might be very wrong but didn't you forget to commit the changes to the database.

In the case of your connection being called conn, conn.commit()

Comment: thank you. Yes I used conn.commit() in the definition of the update_customer() function.